# Android & Stylus detection

Tags: android, hardware

I am toying around with `MotionEvent.getToolType()`.
This function is supposed to be able to differentiate between a finger and a stylus but it does not seem to work with my test stylus and terminals.

So, is this function here only to allow future support for stylus-based digitizer tablets, or is it possible to detect a stylus with any 4.x+ tablet ?

Answer (score 2):

I think this will only work for special styluses with special drivers, and will probably not work with standard capacitive styluses, which work for all touchscreen devices.